# 10進数をASCIIコード文字列に変換するやり方がわからない

Tags: julia

Juliaを使って4という値をASCII表記させたいのですがうまくいきません。
具体的に、4のアスキー文字列はEOTみたいですが([アスキーコード対応表](http://www12.plala.or.jp/mz80k2/electronics/ascii/ascii.html))、

```
Char(4) #'\x04': ASCII/Unicode U+0004 (category Cc: Other, control)
```

となってしまいます。
調べてもなかなかやり方が載っていないため質問させていただきました。
ご教授お願いします

Comment: 質問に書かれた内容だと微妙にどんな結果を得たいのか分からないのですが、`"4"`といった文字列を得たいのなら`string()`なのでは？ [文字列への変換 - Juliaでの整数・浮動小数点数・文字列・文字間の型変換](https://qiita.com/mametank/items/53a2ad40bc9c496734a4#%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B) その辺の得たい結果を追記してみてください。

Comment: ４という値(Int)をASCII形式の文字列に変化させたい　ということです。

Comment: 例えば C言語でいう16進数で`04, 00`という風に 0x00 で終端された2バイトの配列のように見えて欲しいということでしょうか？ それから文字としての`04`は制御コードなのでそれをそのまま文字列として画面表示(例えば`string(Char(4))`)しても単一の文字(フォント)としては表示出来ないのでエスケープシーケンス`"\x04"`になるようですし、それを`print()`や`println()`で表示するとおそらく表示できない制御コードということで`.`となるようですが、そういう形での表示は望んでいないということでしょうか？